# Are there women that can always "select" a spermatozoon with X or Y chromosome?

Tags: genetics

In women when there are spermatozoons near to perform a fecundation, their egg cells emit some substances to attract the spermatozoons they "consider" would be a best match.

Here a link for that study: https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspb.2020.0805

I'd like to know if in that selection there would be cases where the female would only select spermatozoons with the X or the Y chromosome; this would explain cases along the history where a woman couldn't give birth to a child of a certain sex.

Is this selection possible in some women?

Comment: I would say almost impossible to answer because 1) you'd need to extract eggs and work on it, 2) statistics says that the observed even will happen just by chance. For historical cases; how do you know that their next pregnancy wouldn't have been the opposite sex?

Comment: @bob1, if they have done the study that the eggs get to "select" the spermatozoons, I see no reason they could go on the study further to check what it exactly can "select". About historical cases sure, there are not evidence for anything, but they support my hypothesis.

Comment: I'm not sure that there has been any study that shows that the ovum selects sperm based on anything other than being the first to reach it. There are selections based on motility and survival in the different environments of the genital tract in women (pH, mucus, distance...) but nothing to do with the egg. see [here](https://academic.oup.com/humupd/article/21/6/711/629284) for a review (2015).

Comment: I looked at the study briefly and I honestly don't see evidence of a "selection" effect in the way that you're talking about. They find that there are non-random attractant effects between particular male/female donors. But I don't find a convincing mechanism, or even any evidence that particular kinds or classes of sperm can be chosen. There is simply no evidence that the eggs "consider" or "choose" sperm, as opposed to more or less random attraction phenomena. Granted, the researches themselves misleadingly frame it as "mate choice", but that appears to just be hype.